# Incorrect types. Why my new type is Never type?

Tags: typescript, webpack

There is such interface

```
export interface DocExportRequest {
  id: string
  type: 'PDF' | 'CSV'
  [k: string]: any
}
```

Also I have jeneric type, which exclude [k: string] property

```
// see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12215#issuecomment-414782407
// disables `[k: string]: any;` indexing
export type KnownKeys<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: string extends K ? never : number extends K ? never : K
} extends { [_ in keyof T]: infer U }
  ? U
  : never
```

Also I use ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin with config

```
const config = {
  async: isDevelopment,
  useTypescriptIncrementalApi: true,
  checkSyntacticErrors: true,
  reportFiles: ['**', '!**/__tests__/**', '!**/?(*.)(spec|test).*', '!**/src/setupProxy.*', '!**/src/setupTests.*'],
  silent: true,
};
```

and my tsconfig is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
      "@src/*": ["src/*"]
   },
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "webpack-env",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": ["src", "public"]
}
```

When I am applaying KnownKeys to DocExportRequest,

```
type TDocExportReq = KnownKeys<DocExportRequest>
```

I expect that it will be

```
type TDocExportReq {
  id: string
  type: 'PDF' | 'CSV'
}
```

But it return 'never'.  Why?

Before that, the project was bootstrapped with create-react-app with similar configs, and all types were defined correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That implementation of `KnownKeys<T>` was unfortunately broken in TypeScript 4.3; see [microsoft/TypeScript#44142](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44143) for the relevant bug report.  It's marked as "Needs Investigation" so the TS team isn't even sure if it qualifies as a bug or a new limitation, and nobody's even 100% sure what broke it.

Luckily there is a different implementation that works in TypeScript 4.2 and above, which uses [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to suppress index signatures:

```
type KnownKeys<T> = keyof { [P in keyof T as
    string extends P ? never : number extends P ? never : P
    ]: T[P]; };
```

And you can verify that this works:

```
type TDocExportReq = KnownKeys<DocExportRequest>
// type TDocExportReq = "id" | "type"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgEQmwFFxoYAlYARwFdgBneAbwCg4PEATALjiajIA5u04wAnmGB8A5AAV8AMRlwAPnBkBhAMoA1GaI4BtANZ8BwgLp9MScawC+rZwHoXcGAAs86CABs-CAB3YTgIJD9xOCDoEwZEJDgAFW0AFgA6ACY4Wy44ACNgQKDWFwAqVlBIWA9JPABpJGCkeuBxBgAeJIA+OABeODZOOCN6hLgTNoh0ZOt+GEEkIThQVCQueLGAfjgkYAA3NDg+JFoAW0KoFZA1jbht3YOjvnrHa9v45hGAfXHJ8Wmsz4yHQRwAqnAnMMdmDDMdHocoKwyi5XO4vD5-MVQjEoHE4L4rikMtlcjl8hBDqwJFJ7k0gi02p0ev0JlMZl8jHI-uzkjkGHCLEt3sB1vFuTs9oj4acLkdVqK7hKEc84HI4XMklzLABuSE65w0vBJQgkMiwKjUVmNZqtdodU2kaqUGj0JjdUrourJR3ml1WgYAIgQXEDajggaNgaAA)